# Found Bitcoin Core Wallet with unconfirmed Transactions, anything to salvage?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, unconfirmed-transactions

I am currently looking through old .dat files and found a wallet with two "Received with" transactions that are unconfirmed.
When I enter the address from the Label on blockchain.info the address shows a balance of 0 and 0 transactions.

Does that mean, that the transactions are invalid, and that I have to find the origin address to figure out a remaining balance, or is there anything other that I can do?

Bitcoin Core is only synced to 2017 yet.

[image: Bitcoin Core Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Wait till it syncs to today. If remains the same, congratulations, you're $100k richer. Otherwise pretty useless.